# Accessing an app's web history from another app

Tags: android, caching, web, history

I have some apps that I know go out to the web and pull down some pages to be displayed within the application in some type of wrapper (working in Android). I was wondering if there was a way to be able to fetch a list of those web pages, like the application's "web history".

If I could get this in a list somewhere in code that would be awesome, or otherwise just some way to view this. I suppose on the application level it would be different for every app, but if there is someway to fetch this from another app or some type of code that would be awesome!

To sum up, basically I want app A to know what pages app B (an application that I do not own) has fetched and displayed previously.

Comment: To make that work, you need to store that history somewhere that both apps can access.  Perhaps the registry, the file system, or a database.

Comment: Also, I realize this may be some type of protected data within the app, would it be super resource intensive to have some sort of monitoring process to be able to determine which pages a certain application is fetching while it is running?

Comment: Hmm, I should clarify the question. I do not own app B.

Comment: Then you will need to either figure out how app Bsaves the history, OR write a spyware program/sniffer that can monitor network traffic and record it yuorself.  Not a task for the novice.  And frowned-upon behavior at that.

Answer (score 3):

> bascially I want app A to know what pages app B (an application that I do not own) has fetched and displayed previously

Fortunately, this is not directly possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

If App B allows you to configure a proxy server for it, then you can do so, using some proxy server that you manage that can record this info. You can even write an HTTP proxy server to fill this role.

Rooted device users can use Wireshark and equivalent to monitor all network traffic.